# How to use triggers in Mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers, foreign-keys

Guys I'm exploring triggers in MySQL and I'm a bit confused. I have created this tables:

```
persons

pid #primary key
last_name
first_name
```

then this table:

```
employee_hierarchy

emp_id #primary key
pid #foreign key
role
```

And created this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_person_insert 
AFTER INSERT ON persons 
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO employee_hierarchy 
VALUES('','LAST_INSERT_ID()','employee');
```

TRIGGER Successfully created. But whenever I try to insert to persons table, i got a foreign key something error. So I dropped the foreign key and it was a success. But whats the use of this trigger thingy? Can you site a good example where this is useful? cause maybe this is not designed  to update foreign keys, i dont know.

Comment: please post the error you receive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to get a value from `LAST_INSERT_ID()` (BTW you insert a string since it is in quotes) you just need need to read assigned value from `NEW.pid`. It is available to you at this point `AFTER INSERT` of time.

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_person_insert 
AFTER INSERT ON persons 
FOR EACH ROW 
  INSERT INTO employee_hierarchy 
  VALUES(NULL, NEW.pid, 'employee');
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0560e/1)** demo

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. But why does `LAST_INSERT_ID` wont work?

Comment: @user2492415 You're very welcome :) `LAST_INSERT_ID()` won't work for you since you didn't produce any `INSERT` statements in context of a trigger. In that particular case it will always return `0`.